# Rails, how does json.erb works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The case is very simple, I just want to format the json result like this:

```
<%= @cal_dvp_status.to_a.map {|k| [Domain.find(k[0]).name,k[1][0],k[1][1],k[1][2],k[1][3]] } %>
```

@cal_dvp_status is a hash type, so I transfer it by to_a. I need the first column should be Domain's name, the others are number type. But I don't know why the json can't work. But if I just insert the k[0], which is number type, it works.

```
<%= @cal_dvp_status.to_a.map {|k| [k[0],k[1][0],k[1][1],k[1][2],k[1][3]] } %>
```

I don't know why the code doesn't work right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

json.erb is basically the raw json response but with some parts evaluated in ruby. For example, this is a valid json.erb, that produces valid json:

```
{ "status" : "success!" }
```

And this is a valid json.erb that produces a valid json:

```
{ "status" : "<%="success"%>" }
```

and that is it.

You most likely want to use jbuilder or other gem if you are writting complex jsons. 
Otherwise, the handy method `#to_json` from a `Hash` instance returns a json string of that representation. For example, this is a valid json.erb:

```
<%= { :status => "success" }.to_json %>
```

Now you can see what programming logic suits better you.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I've updated it in the respond_to function.